# Reference error in callback to process.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, runtime-error

I need to define a handler for unhandled promise exceptions in a script. I'm using an exception handler I've defined in another module and imported. The Node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) say that "The listener function is called with the following arguments", the error reason and the promise. If I write the command to associate my exception handler with the `unhandledRejection` event like this:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', logPromiseException(error, promise));
```

I get a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: error is not defined
```

If I write the function like this:

```
process.on(
  'unhandledRejection', 
  (error, promise) => logPromiseException(error, promise)
);
```

Everything's okay. Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: by passing `logPromiseException(error, promise)`, you pass the result of the execution of the function with those parameters, not the function itself. To pass the function, use `logPromiseException` without arguments (if you are sure that the callback will be fired with the good arguments in good order), or an anonymous function if you want to control the arguments: `function(unusedArgumentExample, error, promise){ logPromiseException(error, promise); }`

Comment: thanks @Kaddath, if you can move your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: well your question is a duplicate but i have few time right now and couldn't find the dupe quickly, i don't think an answer is appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second parameter is expected to be a function callback, which node will call and pass along the err,promise

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(err,promise){...});
```

here is an simple callback pattern just to demonstrate whats likely to happen behind the secene

```
process.on=function(event,fn){
// assume we have err and promise variable already
if(event==='unhandledRejection')
// execute call back
fn(err,promise);
}
```